# Cron Job is run multiple time on google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, cron

i'm having a website that deploy on Google Cloud. The backend server has a cronjob.

```
func (s *server) startCronJob() error {
    err := s.cron.AddFunc("CRON_TZ=Asia/Saigon 0 9 * * *", s.cronJobFunc)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    s.cron.Start()
    return nil
}
func (s *FBWebHookServer) sendCronProblemToSubscribedUsers() {
    log.Println("Start cron job")
    // DO Smt
    log.Println("Done cron job")
}
```

The `startCronJob` is only run once after the deployment.
But the cron job was ran multiple time.

```
A 2020-03-11T02:00:00.000507Z 2020/03/11 02:00:00 Start cron job 
A 2020-03-11T02:00:00.000513Z 2020/03/11 02:00:00 Start cron job 
A 2020-03-11T02:00:00.000584Z 2020/03/11 02:00:00 Start cron job 
A 2020-03-11T02:00:00.000663Z 2020/03/11 02:00:00 Start cron job
```

I **guess** it's because of multiple deploy. As I dig into this problem, the number of cron job runs is equal the number of deploy time (gcloud app deploy).

Is there any solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Which GCP product do you use? Cloud Functions? App Engine?

Comment: I'm using App Engine

Comment: What is your main ? WHat is your app.yaml file?

Comment: I init *server in main.go and app.yaml only has the go version `runtime: go113`

Comment: Are you saying that each time you deploy your app another instance of the cron job is started or if you deploy multiple services using gcloud app deploy a cron job is started for each of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out myself. 
GCP keeps every old versions of deployment. It doesn't kill old version when i deploy new version.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy
To solve this i have to go to version page and delete all old version.

Comment: it's Instances problem